# Objective-C methods that correspond to these JS methods?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

What NSMutableArray methods correspond to these Javascript Array methods?

- `shift();`
- `unshift();`
- `slice();`
- `splice();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `shift` is a combination of `-objectAtIndex:0` and `removeObjectAtIndex:0`.
- `unshift` is `insertObject:obj atIndex:0`.  It does not return the new length, however.
- `slice` is `-[NSString substringWithRange:]`
- `splice` has no equivalent, though you can approximate it with `insertObjects:atIndexes:`.

Comment: @Moshe the methods are in the answer.  Just invoke them on your `NSMutableArray` (or `NSString`, where noted in the answer) as you would any other method.